# Can I add a new column in a sql table which is already partitioned.(SQL Server )

Tags: sql-server-2000, partition, alter-table

I have a table which is partitioned on x column, but now I want to add new column(y) which is not related to partitioned column. So I used Alter command to add new column(y), but suddenly this y column is taking up all the space. Usually if one job takes 700mb and this new column is alone taking 600mb.

So here my question is, did I followed the correct way to create new column without touching any partition function/scheme.

Thanks in Advance.

I have made the new column as "0", checked the space occupied and can see it is very less compared with the actual value of this column.

With actual value of this column, the job took 1.5 GB space and with "0" it has taken 700 MB only.

Comment: I don't believe SQL Server 2000 supports partitioning, are you really still using such an out-of-date version?

Comment: We are using partitioning, and  yes we are using 2000 version :)